# Pandas groupby applying np.maximum.reduce in a column of arrays

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, pandas-groupby

I need to group the dataframe, applying np.maximum.reduce *(create a new array with the maximum value of each position)* to a column containing numpy arrays

For example:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame([{'name': 'John', 'points' : [1,1,3,5]},{'name': 'John', 'points' : [2,0,1,5]},{'name': 'John', 'points' : [4,1,2,2]}])
df['points'] = df['points'].apply(lambda x : np.array(x)) # converting the list column to pd.array()

df
   name        points
0  John  [1, 1, 3, 5]
1  John  [2, 0, 1, 5]
2  John  [4, 1, 2, 2]
```

If I try using apply(np.maximum) I get the following error:

```
result = df.groupby(['name'])['points'].apply(np.maximum.reduce).reset_index()

ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()
```

**Expected result after the groupby:**

```
   name         points
0  John  [4, 1, 3, 5]
```

---

If I try using np.sum(), the groupby works fine:

```
result = df.groupby(['name'])['points'].apply(np.sum).reset_index()

result
   name         points
0  John  [7, 2, 6, 12]
```

But I need the np.maximum.reduce function apllied:

```
a = np.array([1,1,3,5])
b = np.array([2,0,1,5])
c = np.array([4,1,2,2])
test = np.maximum.reduce([a,b,c])

test
array([4, 1, 3, 5])
```

What is the workaround to achieve this groupby (similar to maximum.reduce), using the numpy efficiency with arrays ?

Comment: Updated my answer with usage of `np.maximum.reduce` and an alternate method.

Comment: It's hard to say without knowing more on the problem, but maybe it's worth separating the points column in four different columns?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to use `np.maximum.reduce` then apply `list` on the grouped values first.

```
df.groupby('name')['points'].apply(lambda x: np.maximum.reduce(list(x)))
```

```
name
John    [4, 1, 3, 5]
Name: points, dtype: object
```

---

**ALTERNATE METHOD:** Lets try apply function with `np.stack` and `np.max`

```
df.groupby('name')['points'].apply(lambda x: np.stack(x).max(0))
```

```
name
John    [4, 1, 3, 5]
Name: points, dtype: object
```

---

Comment: Worked well !  Thank you very much!  
(I thought I had tried this before, apparently I didn't. haha)

Comment: glad to help anytime